# Is there any way to retrieve the database-generated id of a created record during a ReadyAPI test case?

Tags: ready-api

Just getting started with ReadyAPI.

I have a set of REST Apis that handle CRUD operations on a table.  I have a test case in my mind where I create a record, store the id returned, update the record, delete the record and finally use the id to read and assert a not found.

I am probably simply using the wrong search terms, but I can't find any way yet to do the crucial first part - store the id after calling the "create" API.

Comment: If you are just getting started, have you considered the documentation? Maybe this: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/soapui/tutorial/your-first-test/index.html or this: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/properties/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by user Richie in the Smartbear community forums:

---

What you need to do is a property transfer. There's several ways to do this, but the easiest i find considering you're gonna reuse the responseId is to save the responseId to a property step. Once the responseId is saved to a property step you can reuse later in your test.

Some basic steps

- On the Rest request's response, highlight the responseId attribute
  and click on "Transfer to"
- Select 'Add Properties Step'
- Click 'Ok' on 'Create Properties Step' dialogue
- Click 'Ok' on 'Create target property' dialogue
- Click 'Ok' on the 'Transfer to Property' form*

The above generates a 'PropertyTransfer' step and a 'Properties' step.
The resultant of the above steps is that you can then reuse the responseId property value saved in the Properties step on subsequent steps in your test case.

---

Thanks Richie!